# Interpret escaped strings like print does

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have the following string in Python:

```
>>> example="""
... \nthird line
... [\t] <-tab in there
... [\n] <-\\n in there
... \v vtab
... 1\b2 should be only '2'
... this\rthat <- should be only 'that'
... """
```

If I print that, the various escaped characters (like `\t` for a tab) are interpolated into a human readable form:

```
>>> print example


third line
[   ] <-tab in there
[
] <-\n in there

 vtab
2 should be only '2'
that <- should be only 'that'
```

What if I want to only produce a string with the various escape codes expanded or interpreted without printing it? Somthing like:

```
>>> exp_example = example.expandomethod()
```

(I have looked at the various string methods, decode, and format but none are working as in this example.)

---

*Edit*

OK -- Thanks for the help for the thick scull on my part. I was convinced that these strings were being parsed, which they are, but it the display of them that was fooling me.

I worked this out in my own mind:

```
>>> cr='\012'   # CR or \n in octal
>>> len(cr)
1
>>> '123'+cr
'123\n'
>>> '123\012' == '123\n'
True
```

Comment: @Amadan: But what if I want the string with the escape codes interpreted as if printed? I could do a stringIO thingy I suppose, but that seems so unpythonically indirect...

Comment: `StringIO` will preserve every byte you send it. It will not redact contents and act as if it was a terminal.

Comment: print >> tempfile and read it back again?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect the resulting string to be?

Comment: @wim: Yes -- exactly. That would work.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Let `s=\t\n\t` which is 6 ASCII characters. The resulting unescaped string would be 3 byte hex string `0x09 0x0D 0x09` (that has spaces for clarity)

Comment: @drewk: As others have pointed out, the string `"\t\n\t"` isn't six characters long, it's three.  You type six characters in your source code but there are only three in the resulting string.  The resulting string *is* the three-byte string you say you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, when you type in your escaped string, or Python first interprets the string, the escape character `\` and the character following are reduced to the single targeted character.

However -- if you are constructing a string that with to goal of producing unprintable characters from their escape sequence, [str.decode([encoding[, errors]])](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) does what you want:

```
>>> s='string'
>>> esc='\\'
>>> n='n'
>>> st=s+esc+n+'next line'
>>> print st
string\nnextline
>>> print st.decode('string_escape')
string
next line
```

And this:

```
>>> ''.join(['\\','n','\\','t'])=='\n\t'
False
```

is a different result than this:

```
>>> ''.join(['\\','n','\\','t']).decode('string_escape')=='\n\t'
True
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not interpolated. They are printed. For example, `\t` will normally print a number of spaces; `this\rthat` will print `this`, go back and print `that` over it. If you were to print it on a printer, you'd see both words.

If you wanted to reduce a string to a print-equivalent string, I suppose you would have to write your own terminal emulator - I am not aware of any library to do it for you.

A better question is - why do you need it? It looks very much like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are some characters whose representation is different from what they look like when printed. (Newline `'\n'` is just the most obvious one.) You can't really *store* the way these characters look when printed. It would be like asking how to store the way a particular *font* makes a character look.

```
>>> example="""a
... b"""
>>> print example # This is what a newline looks like. You cannot capture it.
a
b
>>> example # This is how a newline is represented.
'a\nb'
```

Answer (score 1):

print doesn't interpret anything. It's already the string itself which has differing internal and external representation.

Proof:

```
s = "\t"
len(s)
```

...yields `1` and not `2`